# Why is `std::declval` specified to return a reference type?

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::declval<T>()` always returns a reference, except if `T` is `void`. Why does it not just return exactly the type you give it? This becomes important with C++17 rules of guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories (https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/value-categories-in-c-17-f56ae54bccbe):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T declval();

template<typename Enable, typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_constructible_impl = false;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_constructible_impl<std::void_t<decltype(T(declval<Args>()...))>, T, Args...> = true;

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr bool is_constructible = is_constructible_impl<void, T, Args...>;

struct non_movable {
    non_movable() = default;
    non_movable(non_movable const &) = delete;
};

static_assert(!std::is_constructible_v<non_movable, non_movable>);
static_assert(is_constructible<non_movable, non_movable>);

constexpr non_movable x = non_movable();
```

See it live: https://godbolt.org/z/zDCDPC

Is there a reason for `std::declval<T>()` to return a reference?

Comment: I suppose to make it possible to use member functions in decltype expressions without the need to go through constructors.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of your question is, exactly. That is, why should `T(declval<T>())` mean the same thing as `T t = T(T{})`?